# Choose way to get reply from form

Tags: website-design, forms, users, contact-us

The traffic from my webpage comes from different social media platforms (Tiktok, Instagram mostly), so in the contact form I wanted to add an option where the user could choose in which of those he wanted to get the reply of the form. Something like this:

[image]

But I don't think the UX is good enough.
What would you suggest in this case?

Comment: What don't you like about the UX?

Comment: "...which of those he wanted to get the reply..." Rather than label "Social Media" use "Send replies to:"

Answer (score 0):

You can usually track the platform that the user came from. Could the platform pass through their handle? Start there - your default "Preferred Contact Method" dropdown is the platform, and the "Handle" is pre-populated with their handle. If the platform is passed through but the handle is not, still pre-populate the platform and let the user fill in the handle.

Having said that - please let the user choose a non-social contact method like email, too. They might not want to connect with companies in a space that they're using for friend and family connections. They might have a special burner email account they use for company outreach, to keep their real inbox free from marketing stuff. And they might prefer SMS contact (very popular with some demographic groups).